# Click each element in an array and extract information

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, loops, web-scraping

I'm currently iterating through elements in an array and manage to get information visible on that element.

But I'd like to click on each element(visible on the left side of the screenshot) in order to extract information that would open on the right side.

How can I click on each of the elements in the array and iterate through them?

See my code below which manages to only iterate and extract data visible from the elements on the left side but doesn't click on each one of them.

```
const listings = $("[role='listitem']")
      .map((index, element) => {
        page.evaluate(() => {
          document.querySelector("[role='listitem']").click();
        });
        const nameElement = $(element).find("._2DX0iPG8PDF3Si_o5PlzIj").text();
        const emailElement = $(element).find("._1e575ojPJe-V4KEJevuytV").text();
        console.log(`name: ${nameElement} and email: ${emailElement}`);
        return { nameElement, emailElement };
      })
      .get();
```

[image]

Comment: You just need to add click event on your list items left side, and up click of any of the element need to pass the id to get the values based on it.

Comment: I added  ```await $(element).find("._2DX0iPG8PDF3Si_o5PlzIj").click();```  but I'm getting an error saying ```UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: $(...).find(...).click is not a function```